# How can I refer to function names stored in a variable as string without invoking them?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

The following snippet should determine all functions that begin with `test_`. However, the code already invokes all functions determined by the `declare` call when passing them to the `beginswith` function.

How can I refer to the function name in a variable without invoking it?

```bash
beginswith() { case "$2" in "$1"*) true;; *) false;; esac; }

get_test_funcs() {
    for func in $(declare -F | awk '{print $3}'); do
        if beginswith "${func}" "test_"; then
            echo "${func}"
        fi
    done
}

get_test_funcs
```

Comment: Your beginswith function is wrong, swap `$2` and `$1` and try again

Comment: The whole script can be condensed to something like this: `declare -F | sed -n 's/^declare -f \(test_.*\)/\1/p'`

Comment: `beginswith() { [[ "$1" == "$2"* ]]; }` - simpler implementation. So simple it's not worth putting in a function even.

Comment: @Verpous : Dropping the unnecessary quotes would make it even simpler.

Comment: I don't see any place in your script which would invoke all functions. Point out the line where this would happen.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin `declare -F|awk '$3~"^test_"{print$3}'`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it like this:

```bash
get_test_funcs() {
    declare -F | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | grep '^test_'
}

for testfunc in $(get_test_funcs); do
    "${testfunc}"
done
```

So, `get_test_funcs()` determines all functions beginning with `test_` without invoking them and in the following `for` loop, determined functions are called sequentially.

Comment: Would be much shorter and simpler  `declare -F | awk '$3~"^test_"{print$3}'`

Comment: @LéaGris : you can further simplify that to just `awk '($_=$3)~"^test_"'`

Answer (score 0):

Could be made simpler by

```
declare -F | grep -oP ' \Ktest_.*'
```

The  `\K` anchors the subsequent expression after a space (so that you don't catch a function named `xxxtest_foo`, and the `-o` ensures that only the function names are printed, not the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either the `NF` way, the `index()` way, or the `regex` way :

> ```
> declare -F | nawk '$(NF = NF) ~ "^test_"' FS='^.+ ' OFS=
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> declare -F | mawk 'NF*=!_<NF' OFS='test_' FS='.+ test_'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> declare -F | gawk 'index($_=$NF, "test_") == !_'
> ```